# How to Return Char Array?

Tags: c, arrays, function

As you can see I have this code it takes a command (char array ) and divides it into two diffrent arrays if there is "|" between them.What I want is not to print it with the function but return these two new arrays to main and then print them ?

How can I do it ?

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    int status,n,i;
    char command[4000];
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,"Shell>",6);
    n=read(STDIN_FILENO,command,4000);
    void getArguments(char **,char*);
    char *getStdOutFileName(char *);
    if(n>0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            bugrafonk(command,&i);
            printf("%s",First);
            printf("%s",Second);
        }
    }
}

void bugrafonk(char* c,int*length)
{
    int i;
    int a;
    char First[4000];
    char Second[4000];
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(c[i]=='|')
        {
            i=a;
            for(i=0;i<a;i++)
            {
                char First[i];
            }
            printf("---");
            for(i=a;a<length;i++)
            {
                char Second[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return(First,Second);                   //is this  true ?
}
```

There are some unnecssery declaration in the main now just avoid them I will use them later on.

Comment: Wow. Please format your code correctly - that is hideous.

Comment: Try to build it, read the errors, I mean actually *read* them (it seems to be to uncommon these days), and fix the errors one by one. Then realize that you can't return a pointer to a local array, as the array like any other local variable will go out of scope once the function returns.

Comment: `char* bugrafonk` instead of `void bugrafonk` and `return First` or `return Second` instead of `return(char First,char Second)`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg 95% of the time understanding the meaning of an error message helps both, fixing it, and understanding how things work.

Comment: For now I got segmantation fault error.I am trying to build with linux.I have formatted the code also chanced the return values and function itself is it corret now ?

Comment: you can pass a char * as a argument and any changes on it will also be reflected from the main function also

Comment: You would seldom want to "return an array". That breaks RAII and is generally "not the C way". You normally take a pointer to a chunk of data and modify it.

Comment: I dont understand can you please explain it as a answer ?

Comment: Note that you actually have two questions rolled into one: how to return arrays, and how to return multiple values.

Comment: Yeah exactly I want to return to char arrays from my function to main then print it.Please I am an amateur can you guys post your thoughts on answers ?

Comment: One basic fault is that `bugrafonk` has no prototype and so the compiler will assume its arguments and its return value (if any) are `int`.

Comment: That must be int right int bugrafonk ?

Comment: Btw, turn on compiler warnings, and fix them. For example, you pass `length` as pointer. Yet you seem to use it as integer. Do you know what a "pointer" is in C? If not, you should probably start simpler...

Answer (score 1):

To retun char * to main **you need to send pointers to your function** which are attached to memory that you can use

For example,

```
....
char return1[50]
char return2[50]
....
split_function(command, return1, return2);
....
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on where you store the results of your calculations.
In your current implementation both `First` and `Second` arrays are allocated inside the `bugrafonk` function and thus will be destroyed when the function is finished.

One possible option would be to allocate memory for result arrays outside the function and pass pointers to the function.

```
char first[4000], second[4000];
bugrafonk(..., first, second);
// use first and second
```

And bugrafonk implementation:

```
void bugrafonk(your arguments..., char *first, char *second)
{
    ...
}
```

Also, I have no idea what the mysterious word `bugrafonk` means ;)

Comment: Anyway so if I didnt send those to arrays as arguments into the function I cant return them ?

Comment: In C you can return only one variable from function. The usual practice when you have to return many is to pass pointers to variables (or data) as parameters to function, change variables/data inside the function, then just exit. When the function finishes you will have access to you changed data. If you absolutely want to return multiple parameters, have a look at python ;)

Answer (score 0):

The function implemented here splits the string by terminating the first part, and returns a pointer to the second part.

You don't need to return 2 pieces of information since you already know where the first string is. Note that this will not work if a **string literal** is passed since you cannot modify it, but that's not the case here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* bugrafonk(char* c);                   // function prototype

int main(void)
{
    char command[4000];
    char *split;
    scanf("%3999s", command);               // enter limited length string
    split = bugrafonk(command);             // this splits the string
    printf("First part: %s\n", command);    // print first half
    if (split != NULL)                      // if there is a second half
        printf("Second part: %s\n", split); // print second half
}

char* bugrafonk(char* c)                    // returns string pointer
{
    char *cptr = strchr(c, '|');            // find that char
    if (cptr != NULL)                       // if it was found
    {
        *cptr = '\0';                       // terminate first part here
        cptr++;                             // advance pointer to next part
    }
    return cptr;
}
```

Program output:

```
one|two
First part: one
Second part: two
```

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to return a pointer to char, and then pass *two* arrays that will be modified in the body of the function.:

```
char *func(char arr[], char* arr2 /* other parameters */)
{   /* process arr and arr2 */        

    // return new array one. arr2 doesn't need to be returned.
    return arr; 
}

// in main:
char command[4000];
char arr2[4000];                  // First
char *arr3 = func(command, arr2); // Second
```

Or just pass all arrays as arguments to the function and then return `void`, since they will be modified in the function.